# Searching for CSS functions nodes Protractor

Tags: html, css, angular, protractor

I have the following code and am unable to find the "Login" words using Protractor:

```html
<div _ngcontent-c2="" class="align-center">
  <img _ngcontent-c2="" alt="Autoprax" class="ap-logo" src="/images/apLogoSmall.svg" style="width: 100%">
  <h2 _ngcontent-c2="">Login</h2>
</div>
```

and am searching it using the following on protractor:

```css
    it('Check Proper Login Page', function() {
    var login = element(by.nodeName('[.H2="Login()"]'));
    expect(login.getText()).toBe('Login');
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is off, it should be `by.css('.align-center h2')`.

Also, you should add classes and ids to your elements to make sure that Protractor finds them. The selector I suggest works fine in the snippet you provided but might fail miserably in the full page, as `.align-center` is too generic of a class to use reliably.

Comment: a possible workable locator in full page:  `by.css('img[src*="apLogoSmall"] + h2')`